# Rebalancing Cassandra 1.2 cluster when a seed node (from total of 2) is died using virtual nodes

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I have a Cassandra 1.2 cluster in my local machine with modified hosts:

```
#cassandra nodes
m.y.i.p               m.y.i.p   (Node 1)<---- seed 1
m.y.i.p               127.0.0.3 (Node 2)
m.y.i.p               127.0.0.4 (Node 3)<---- seed 2
m.y.i.p               127.0.0.5 (Node 4)
m.y.i.p               127.0.0.6 (Node 5)
```

... so the cluster has a total of 5 nodes. I'm using Virtual Nodes, so I don't havo to set initial_token anywhere.

The steps I've followed:

1. Start the seed nodes (1 and 3)
2. Start Nodes 2 and 4.
3. Turn off Node 3.
4. Try to join Node 5.

The problem is in the 4th step, when I try to join Node 5 Cassandra throws this Exception:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (-7204018021044318047,-6965052533844316617]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getRangeFetchMap(RangeStreamer.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:890)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:659)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:514)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:411)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:278)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:366)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:409)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (-7204018021044318047,-6965052533844316617]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getRangeFetchMap(RangeStreamer.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:890)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:659)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:514)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:411)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:278)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:366)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:409)
Exception encountered during startup: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (-7204018021044318047,-6965052533844316617]
ERROR 16:55:47,634 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:321)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:479)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The range (-7204018021044318047,-6965052533844316617] just belongs to the died node (Node 3). Due to I'm using Virtual Nodes, I think that the ring must be rebalance:

> Rebalancing a cluster is no longer necessary when adding or removing nodes. When a node joins the
>   cluster, it assumes responsibility for an even portion of data from the other nodes in the cluster. If a node
>   fails, the load is spread evenly across other nodes in the cluster.

But I'm wrong, obviously :).

What can I do to join a new node in a existing cluster when a previous node is down? Please, note that I have 256 tokens per node, nodetool move isn't an option (I think).

Thank you in advance, any info will be welcome!

Comment: What is your replication factor?  If 1 then it will fail because the data cannot be streamed to the new node.

Comment: I'm using SimpleStrategy with replication_factor 3. But, do I need to have data to rebalance? I mean, If I have only the ring, without any keyspace, and one node fails, Don't divide tokens again? Thank you for your answer Richard.

Comment: Adding a new node should always work when there are no column families.  Adding a node should work with RF 3 with or without data even if one or two nodes are down.  It might be a bug - maybe bootstrapping a new node with one down when using virtual nodes doesn't work.  I'll try to repro if I have a minute.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, very kind. I've tried with less tokens, different node number, others RF and strategies... but I always get the same result, I don't find the configuration error.

Comment: Does it start with node 3 up?  Why do you need node 3 down?

Comment: I don't need Node 3 down, I'm just testing the behavior when a seed node fails. I want to know if the other seed node can bootstrap new nodes and if a virtual node structure is able to rebalance tokens.

Comment: It's done, I must remove the node manually.

Comment: `(-7204018021044318047,-6965052533844316617]` Whoa..

Comment: It's a strange range uh @Neil :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove  Node 3 (which was turned off) from the token manually.